# Evaluate $\int_o^{\pi ^2\over4}\cos^2(\sqrt{x})\, \operatorname d\!x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I want to integrate following:
$$\int_o^{\pi ^2\over4}\cos^2(\sqrt{x})\,dx.$$
I try solve instead:
$$\int_o^{\pi ^2\over4}\frac{\cos(2\sqrt{x})+1}{2} \,dx.$$
but I can't integrate $\cos(2\sqrt x)$

Comment: "To integrate by the method of integration"? What did you actually mean to say?

Comment: Substitute $u = \sqrt x, \frac{dx}{du} = 2u$

Comment: @DonAntonio I copied the form of question from an other question. It was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change variable $x=\frac{y^2}{4}$. The problem of the antiderivative of  $\cos(2\sqrt x)$ becomes : find the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{2} y \cos \left(y\right)$. Then, integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi^2}4} \cos^2(\sqrt x)\ dx & = \int_0^{\frac\pi2} 2u\cos^2(u)\ du
\end{align*}$$
Now try to integrate $\cos^2$ by means of partial integration and then apply partial integration with $\underbrace{2u}_{\downarrow} \underbrace{\cos^2 u}_{\uparrow}$

> $$\int \cos^2 u\ du = \frac12 (\cos u \sin u + u)$$